# No matching function call to std::visit() using overload pattern

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to dispatch a variant inside a variant with the visitor overload pattern. However I can't seem to fit the parameters to what is expected. I get this (truncated, for more output see compiler explorer link):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'visit ...'
```

Here's my code. What am I overlooking?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGxcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQS/qQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BAUGp6Y4CYRHRLHEJXEl2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn6Btpj2RQwNTQQlUbHxibaNza25HQrjA%2BFD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWADUJrtuAG5NeIYEZ9gmGgCCewdHmKfnyDP4qPePL2eBEwLGSBmBnzcBAAnslGKxMAA6ZHHAAqCn%2BzxmxC8DmOqAu8VoqCY6GOIDRCmRiIBJgA7FZnsdmccvOkjJSQCBUHDiEwiMQIMtjtSzoyXnSACJi2nPcIEY4sJjhIWnBmyp4s47Y3EKvrAiVWKUypksnV4/WYI1G6W7cVa816xrAtz0m0mwGalls8LAbXOzAAfRhcM%2Bkv96C5V2IN0EZzclqepGOlpsKYDrt2DztAK1TC8RH9/I%2BZ3DM2LwdhmDdibd9Olxpzz1zZoIOLx2EJgkN9Y9DrbuuOncYBGtvabnv77YVAHU8DQPAwIg5MOhIqhgXXG/bW9Oh8RiCR15v1duNVqfRyAIpeTC3gBq11uqKrYYjUafcfOPy5LAEaQDZM5wXARl2BNcN0wZNsAPI9IP%2BCctRbZlLz9TAuwIStQ1Ld8QGjWM7m/AhIxAP8GAA4tkxvO9MEfGNnyraCMKTIcMKsLM%2BxZfNC3Qkc314wQsOrBlh27LcG1tcVkOOfhiGOCB0gALyDBU8FLDQxWOPBIWOLgNLtLTrGsYU61NLVmXLCEcJ/PC8EKCACSJEl0FMr1zPMkwAFYrDMfwvMlCBqIfT8CBfOFzD83zjnw25k24v5fIiotgWDUFhQAWnuZKVNfVz3Py1sSIuOzCAcwliGJUk8oKmrmS8ny/M8gLgLwRcwNXY9q0S3y4oLBLIv8ZZqtqkbjmSGNBCoCBzDMFq2tqcDOuOF5PLcBgZqGxDRvy%2BtSGk7aWXqiL/IgGDD2ITrjp6454quwbhoO/LxvlKaZrOuCIRWtaNs4x7DqlPazL%2B05vOOpqIFu7qkhuvq7qG9UgeBllnsm6azDMAB5AgEHiLSGGOIKPhiuNVvW9HNp3JHdv2kbdtw2SAHcmhc84sEOENMAgYmCE27AuZC1Z6ZIJniBZtw2doDmFIDVLkl56WKwINKKZp2riEwAgNnxy1XVPSTVY8gGDaQ0HEvByGBuTNAGBmdNixeXyMqyyycuwhG3O2lGCFe9HLWWrzvvJ37tvVzXiG1jNxODgrqcRnbTcagKLYiq2BFt1MIqdrNsqEtVKc9ibvbRsw/asUmfq2g7Q61u2DSjyuatjj2Y4Tk7k%2Bu6308jx3jky7OXdzh7Rq9n2S4DY5XSDhvRur8Pa6tev85jo247qgHcL/QkIAEnnkxdlWgd7ZspQ4VZaE4TzeD8DgtFIVBOEnnyLG1dZNhLMxdh4UgCE0U/VgAaxAJITyiJ/BmE8nSTyABOSQVQ6T%2BDpFA3Y%2BhOCSCvr/O%2BnBeAKBABob%2Bv9VhwFgDARAKBUCgjoPEcglA0AUPoAkYAChmDJAUAgDcpAsDFS2PePAmAGYYzhNfL%2BNBJbxBwRAGIGCYjhCaNCTgX9pHMGINCDGMRtALXkbwWhbBBAYwYLQORN9eBYCVEYcQRiOF4HVnUQkOCLGYFULUAs2xb7yi6Bg2geAYh8mUR4LAGC2x4BYJo1YVADCMJ4XwgRjBNEyEECIMQ7ApBxPkEoNQGDdBBAMEYFARlLD6C8TgyAqweQ9DselH4pZTCWGsGYDQvcMYKF7jOMQtBe7JGxurUkvBHIHjwFgIpQpOjdEyC4Bg7hPBtCAZ5YI4zBhlAqCAZBBQMgCEmH4YBKQ0irIYPM4YCRkE1DqAIPoExJm5E2Ucnopy5ilH2UssY/R1nTMec0PZiwDmrAUK/LYEgz4X3QRY%2B%2BHBjiqAABz%2BHSv4SQxxgDIGQPJAcDB/7ClOvgAUpwP5cGWLwH%2BRjlirBxqSEYQzAGeTwefDgaDSDBPJaQa%2Bt9gXYNwfg/FpAiGkPWAQZIBZqEQFockShF0EScHBZC6FsL4W6TMIiMwvBVyEBIP0vQ/B4miHEMk1VqSVDqAsZk0gDM%2BTJBCSgjgl96UYOBRjAsPKFSoCoKCiFUKYVwoRRAJFKL5IeDobjPY2LcUEMJZgYlCQhmUupbSvBDKelYNsCyvFWgCWkDJZIREuw6SSDMJIDQnkwW7A/nUsFprdiAsZbGhNf9TVyotUC8tgbSDlXSM4SQQA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <variant>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename... Ts>
struct overload : Ts...
{
    using Ts::operator() ...;
};

int main() {

    struct StateA{};
    struct StateB{};
    struct StateC{};

    using state_type = std::variant<StateA, StateB, StateC>;
    auto state = state_type{StateA{}};

    struct EventA{};
    struct EventB{};

    struct WifiConnectedNote{};
    struct ErrorNote{};

    using QueueVariantType = std::variant<std::monostate, WifiConnectedNote, ErrorNote>;
    
    using event_type = std::variant<std::monostate, QueueVariantType, EventA, EventB>;
    auto event = event_type{EventA{}};

    for (size_t i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        state = std::visit(overload{
            [&](QueueVariantType&& variant, auto&& state_tmp) -> state_type {
                std::visit(overload{
                    [&](WifiConnectedNote&&, auto&&){
                        printf("WifiConnectedNote A\n");
                    },
                    [&](ErrorNote&&, auto&&){
                        printf("ErrorNote A\n");
                    },
                    [&](auto&&, auto&&){
                        printf("Other in Queue variant\n");
                    },
                }, std::forward<decltype(variant)>(variant), std::forward<decltype(state_tmp)>(state_tmp));
                return StateC{};
            },
            [&](auto&&, const StateA&) -> state_type {
                printf("State A\n");
                return StateC{};
            },
            [&](auto&&, const StateB&) -> state_type {
                printf("State B\n");
                return StateA{};
            },
            [&](auto&&, const StateC&) -> state_type {
                printf("State C");
                return StateB{};
            },
        }, std::move(event), state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are missing an overload case for the outer `std::visit` for `event==std::monostate`. Either provide one or remove the state from the variant type.

  ```
    [&](std::monostate, auto&& ) -> state_type {
        ; // Do stuff here
    }
  ```
- `state_tmp` is not used in the inner `std::visit`. If i remove it and the `auto&&` from the lambda signatures, the code compiles and runs. But is this what you want ? Remember that `state_tmp` is not the variant type itself, but the underlying type resolved by the outer std::visit. That's why the inner visit fails.

Hope you can take from here !

Comment: Thank you, you are right! Interestingly I thought that auto&& in combination with either state as the second parameter would capture any event, so monostate would also be captured. Why is this not the case?

Comment: 1st pointc does not make sence. What's the difference between `monostate` and `EventA` or `EventB`. 2nd point is a direct hit.

Comment: @glades ,  @Red.Wave : I do not know why `auto&&` would not match a `monostate` (and i agree that it should), but fact is that gcc will not compile. A web search turned nothing up for me on that topic, maybe you have more luck.